# Are Maven Central and JCenter vulnerable for typosquatting?

Tags: java, maven, security, gradle

Are Maven Central and JCenter vulnerable for typosquatting? Can one get malicious dependency by misspelling artifact IDs? What can be done to metigate the risks?

Comment: @NathanHughes, let's say I don't use any of them as a proxy. My build directly fetches artifacts from public repositories. BTW: where can I find more information about excluding features you mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using central/JCenter directly (as you mentioned in your comments) I would recommend never to build inside a company infrastructure cause that would open an attack vector (in theory). In such cases always build on an open infrastructure like travis, circleci etc.

If someone want's to place an malicious artifact into Central (I can't speak for JCenter; If I correctly remember more or less the same) based on the scenario you have described this would require an access for a single (bad) person to have access to a known group which contains artifacts which are good known and most important being used on a wide area. This means this bad person needs to have the permission to publish an artifact through the different areas including signing the artifact.

Ok let us assume someone has got over the previous described barriers.

So the artifact needs to be named very similar to other artifacts. And now someone needs to make a particular typo that this particular artifact will be picked up. Second it's needs to be executed somehow (Maybe unit tests/integrations tests might be possible).

So in the end I would say: In theory yes practically very unlikely.

But of course 100% safety is not possible so general advices:

- Transfer always via https (TLSv1.2 at least)
- Check the checksums of the artifacts (fail your build if the [checksums do not fit](https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/))
- Use review process during development

So I can only recommend to use a [repository manager](https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2016/05/15/how-important-is-a-repository-manager/) inside a company and of course use a security scanner which checks for known vulnerabilities etc.

Furthermore all repository managers have the option to block any dependencies before using and make a kind of approval process possible inside your company with the drawback of taking time here which "might" buy more safety.

Comment: What if we change it a bit: imagine case of typo in group id. Then according to scenario you described whole first the most tricky part is gone.

Comment: > "I would recommend never to build inside a company infrastructure cause that would open an attack vector (in theory)." Well, it is not really possible when people work on opensource project.

Comment: Very simple if you are working on an open source project use the open build infrastructures as I already mentioned (for example travis/circleci etc.). Second if you have typo in your groupId you very likely have a non existing artifact..the same as mentioned for the other things...my conclusion keeps the same...

Comment: Regarding first - while CI can be moved to public infrostructure, developers still anyway need to run builds on their local machines during development cycle. Regarding second - who prevents one from creating, for example, org.apache.conmons group and putting there poisoned artifacts with correct artifact IDs?

Comment: If you are really that concerned that you should prevent working on open source like this. Apart from that you don't need to built locally. Working on branches can be done and built on open source infrastructure. No need to built locally (if your really would like to work like that way).

Comment: Second the groupId already held by Apache Software Foundation  which means you need to become a committer (or being one) to get somehow some kind of artifacts into Apache's repository manager  under that groupId If you do several other people will see that..and need to vote on a release using a valid GPG key etc. afterwards those artifacts will be synched to Central. Formally the artifacts can be checked on each projects website (for Apache Software Foundation projects) which can be checked with GPG and SHA512 checksums and if you really that concerned downloaded and propagated manually...

Comment: But org.apache.coNmons is not, so one can create it and put poisoned artifacts there.

Comment: Ok Ok. That groupId is already kept by Apache Software Foundation and if you like to request access to Central based on that you will be rejected usually groupId are lowercase only cause they are DNS reverse names. etc. We can discuss endless. The point is as I already mentioned: 100% safety is not possible. If you going that path you need to download the source packages only build them yourself. But that means also you need to build your used OS from source code all the tools you use from source cause they can be attacked too. I don't really understand your concern? What is the real problem?